# How can I make multiple checkboxes checked in Angular where checkbox value is in one column of database with csv?

Tags: node.js, angular, database, checkbox

`editStatusObj.categories` values comes from database like (1,15,23) in one column, if there is only one value available then it shows checkbox checked, but how can I show multiple checked using multiple values in angular?

**edit-status.component.html**

```html
<div>
  <label *ngFor="let statusCategoryObj of statusCategoryObj"> 
    <mat-checkbox  value="{{statusCategoryObj.categorytitle}}" [checked]="statusCategoryObj.id == editStatusObj.categories" name="categories" (change)="onCheckboxChange(statusCategoryObj,$event)">
      {{statusCategoryObj.categorytitle}}</mat-checkbox> 
  </label>
</div>
```

**edit-status.component.ts**

```js
editStatusObj : Status = new Status();
statusCategoryObj : Category[];

ngOnInit() {
 const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.statusService.editStatusDetailsById({'id': id}).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      if(data.status == 28){
       editStatusObj.id = data.payload[0].id;
       editStatusObj.categories = data.payload[0].categories;
      }
    }
  )

  this.statusService.getCategoryInStatus(em).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      if(data.status == 23){
        statusCategoryObj.id = data.payload.id;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

app.js(node side code)

```
app.post('/editStatusDetailsById',function(req,res){
  connection.query('SELECT id,categories from status WHERE id = ?',[req.body.id], function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
   res.send({
     'status':'28',
     'success': 'true',
     'payload': results,
     'message':'one language is edited'
   });
  });
});
```

status.ts

```
export class Status {
   constructor(public id : number = null,
               public languages : string = "") { }
}
```

statuscategory.ts

```
export class StatusCategory {
constructor(public id : number = null,
            public categorytitle : string = "",
           ){}
```

Comment: whats the error?? i think you can achieve it by your code only if data is proper.

Comment: No errors data fetched properly but i want to display multiple checkbox is checked where checkbox multiple values stored in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed `editStatusObj` as an Object Array.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ic5r1b-tkmwms)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label *ngFor="let statusCategoryObj of statusCategoryObj;let i = index"> 
    <mat-checkbox  value="{{statusCategoryObj.categorytitle}}" [checked]="checkedCategories(statusCategoryObj.id)" name="categories" (change)="onCheckboxChange(statusCategoryObj,$event)">
      {{statusCategoryObj.categorytitle}}</mat-checkbox> 
  </label>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  categories: Array<any> = [];
  statusCategoryObj: Array<any> = [
    { category: 1, id: 1, categorytitle: 'cat 1' },
    { category: 2, id: 2, categorytitle: 'cat 2' },
    { category: 3, id: 3, categorytitle: 'cat 3' },
  ];

  editStatusObj: Array<any> = [
    { categories: '1,3,5', id: 1, categorytitle: 'cat 1' },
  ]
  ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.statusService.editStatusDetailsById({'id': id}).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      if(data.status == 28){
      this.editStatusObj.id = data.payload[0].id;
      this.editStatusObj.categories = data.payload[0].categories;
      this.allCategories = this.editStatusObj.categories.split(',');
     }        
    }
   )
  }

   checkedCategories(id){
     for(var i = 0 ; i < this.allCategories.length; i++){
       if(id == this.allCategories[i]){
         return true;
       }
     }  
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Aj attempt my question, issue is that     { categories: 1,15,33 , id: 1, categorytitle: 'cat 1' } categories have multiple value

Comment: Is there only one "{ categories: 1,15,33 , id: 1, categorytitle: 'cat 1' }"??

Comment: no there where multiple rows categories : '1,15,33' in string

Comment: I am asking about?? object { categories: 1,15,33 , id: 1, categorytitle: 'cat 1' }?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178244/discussion-between-unluckyaj-and-amisha-rana).

Comment: Welcome @Amisha.