# AngularJS filter based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, filtering

I have created a function that is supposed to filter displayed data based on checkbox selection. However, I am having trouble displaying the correct data. The checkboxes are working and everything but I am having trouble pushing the selected checkbox value into the data and getting the output.

[image]

I need to select the checkbox to show data that contains that H value.

[image]

So basically there are 4 checkboxes associated with the type field you see in the screenshot above. Let's say I select H. I need only data where the type = H to show. I will attach some code below of what I have so far. I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
var filterOtb = function (keepOpen, types) {
var filtered = data;
var checkedTypes = [];

console.log('filtered = ', filtered);

scope.types.forEach(function(code) {
 if (code.selected) {
  checkedTypes.push(code.type);
  console.log('selected checkbox', checkedTypes);
 }
});

if (scope.validDates.from) {
 filtered = filterOtbByDateRange();
}

if (modal && !keepOpen) {
 modal.hide();
}
return filtered;
```

}

There is a separate function running in there that filters the keys shown in the screenshots by the date. Please ignore that function... Any help is appreciated as I have been stuck on this for days...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896655/how-to-make-multiple-checkbox-checked-in-angular-where-checkbox-one-column-in-da refer this question

Answer (score 0):

It pretty simple with underscore, you can pass filter value for one or many properties.

```
let listOfPlays = 
    [
    {title: "The Rambo", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1520},
    {title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
    {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
    {title: "The Dog", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1900}
    ]


_.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611});
=> [{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
    {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}]
```

Comment: I am fairly new to AngularJS so I'm not really sure how to implement this with my code...

Comment: just include this in index.html, or you can download file locally than include it.
[underscore](https://underscorejs.org/)
`<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>`

Comment: I am already using that library I just don't know how your answer answers my question...

Answer (score 0):

Check this code for filter array;

```js
 var data = [{ id: '1', type: 'H' }, { id: '2', type: 'H' }, { id: '3', type: 'M' }, { id: '4', type: 'G' }, { id: '5', type: 'J' }, { id: '6', type: 'G' }];
    var types = ['H', 'G'];  

    var filter = function (data, types) {
        return data.filter(item => types.includes(item.type));
    }
    console.log(filter(data, types));
```

```js
    var data = [
        { id: '1', type: 'H' },
        { id: '2', type: 'H' },
        { id: '3', type: 'M' },
        { id: '4', type: 'G' },
        { id: '5', type: 'J' },
        { id: '6', type: 'G' }
    ];

    var types = [
        { type: 'H', selected: true },
        { type: 'M', selected: true },
        { type: 'G', selected: false },
        { type: 'J', selected: false }];

    var filterOtb = function (types) {
        var filtered = data;
        var checkedTypes = [];
        console.log('filtered = ', filtered);
        types.forEach(function (code) {
            if (code.selected) {
                checkedTypes.push(code.type);
                console.log('selected checkbox', checkedTypes);
            }
        });
        return data.filter(item => checkedTypes.includes(item.type));
        
      
    }
    console.log(filterOtb(types));
```

Comment: Could you write this based on my code snippet... so I know where this code belongs... ? thanks

Comment: I change the method